# How to write EF query to table with multiple foreign keys without putting it at the start of the query?

Tags: entity-framework-core

EDIT:

I'm one step closer to what I'm after. I added a navigation property to Skills which allowed me to `ThenInclude` the Skill Responses as seen below.

My only problem now is that I'm not sure how to filter the Skill Responses such that it only includes those for the current UserAssessment. How can I do this?

```
var userAssessmentQuery = AppDbContext.UserAssessments
    .Include(o => o.User)
    .Include(o => o.Assessment)
    .ThenInclude(o => o.Categories)
    .ThenInclude(o => o.Competencies)
    .ThenInclude(o => o.Skills)
    .ThenInclude(o => o.Responses.Where(o => o.UserAssessmentId == ???);
```

Original Post:

The first query below is the working code I have and then the following two are an example that would technically return the data I want but not in a friendly format and then an example that won't compile but might work if I knew what steps to take to make it work.

I can think of ways to accomplish what I need to do, however I'm certain there is/are one or more "proper/correct" way(s) to do this in EF of which I am unaware. That is, I'm sure I could do two queries and then manually put the data together how I want it but that doesn't seem very smart.

```
public async Task<UserAssessment> GetFirstAssessment()
        {
            // This works and is essentially what I want, but I also need to add users' responses to skill questions
            var userAssessmentQuery = AppDbContext.UserAssessments
                .Include(o => o.Assessment)
                .ThenInclude(o => o.Categories)
                .ThenInclude(o => o.Competencies)
                .ThenInclude(o => o.Skills);


            // This technically could work but totally ruins the json structure I would like to output
            var userAssessmentQueryWithResponses = AppDbContext.SkillResponses
                .Include(o => o.UserAssessment)
                .ThenInclude(o => o.Assessment)
                .ThenInclude(o => o.Categories)
                .ThenInclude(o => o.Competencies)
                .ThenInclude(o => o.Skills);

            // This is closer to what I want, but doesn't work because I don't have anything directly on the AssessmentSkill class/table indicating 
            // it is related to the SkillResponse class/table. It's also problematic because the responses also has a foreign key to the UserAssessment
            // which has to be taken into account as well.

            //var userAssessmentQueryWithResponses = AppDbContext.UserAssessments
            //    .Include(o => o.Assessment)
            //    .ThenInclude(o => o.Categories)
            //    .ThenInclude(o => o.Competencies)
            //    .ThenInclude(o => o.Skills)
            //    .ThenInclude(o => o.SkillResponse);

            var assessment = await userAssessmentQuery.FirstAsync();
            return assessment;
        }
```

Comment: Add desired JSON output and I'll show sample. You do not need Include if you write custom projection via `Select`.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Go to https://skillswebd001.azurewebsites.net/app/getfirstassessment. It's very close to what I need. Only two changes I want. 1st, I want the UserAssessment to be at the root. That's easy and is the result of the 1st query in my post. 2nd, under the skills I want the SkillResponses... *but* it should only be responses for the current UserAssessment. The SkillResponses table has a UserAssessmentId foreign key and a SkillId foreign key. I think that this comment combined with my OP is all the info you should need but let me know if you need me to share anything more. Thanks!

Comment: Does your 'UserAssessments' entity not have a navigation property for its 'Responses' entities, assuming that there is a relationship?

Comment: @Vince I did add one since I wrote the above, but it didn't help. Well, it's a little help if I wanted to `Include` the responses directly under the UserAssessment. However, I want to `ThenInclude` them under the Skills. I don't know how to do that (if there is a way?) so I tried writing a `Select` query to project the data manually as mentioned in the answer below but it still doesn't work. I will have an opportunity to meet with someone who may be able to help tomorrow, so I will either update with the solution or else update with more details about the problem at that point.

Comment: @Vince I forgot to mention an important point, that I can `ThenInclude` the responses under the skills and it will work, however it will give me everyone's responses and not just the responses for the current UserAssessment. If I manually project using `Select` and try to add a `Where` method to filter it based on the UserAssessmentId then it compiles but throws an error at runtime. Without the `Where` it runs fine (but obviously data is not right). I don't know how to do equivalent of `Where` when using `Include` and `ThenInclude` methods, if that's even possible?

Comment: @Vince It's also possible that the way I've designed the tables is not ideal... I don't think that's the case, but I will be speaking with someone who can hopefully steer me in the right direction soon if that's the case.

Answer (score 0):

For selecting appropriate structure you have to use custom projection. In this case you do not need `Include` at all.

This is just sample how to process entities:

```cs
var query = 
  AppDbContext.UserAssessments.Select(ua => new
  {
     id = ua.Id,
     assessments = ua.Assesments.Select(a => new
     {
        id = a.Id,
        tentantId = a.TentantId,
        title = a.Title,
        categories = a.Categories.Select(c => new 
        {
           id = c.Id,
           assesmentId = c.AssesmentId,
           title = c.Title,
           quote = c.Quote,
           competencies = c.Competencies.Select(com => new
           {
               id = com.Id,
               assessmentCategoryId = com.AssessmentCategoryId,
               title = com.Title,
               question = com.Question,
               skills = com.Skills.Select(s => new {...}).ToArray()
               ...
           }).ToArray()
        }).ToArray()
  });

var result = await query.FirstAsync();
```

Comment: Your example projects to the same level I already have using `Include` and `ThenInclude`. But I need to get the SkillResponses under the Skills though. And it must only include SkillResponses for the current UserAssessment. I think I need to add a navigation property (or properties) to my SkillResponse class, but I am just now trying to read up on that as I am somewhat new to EF. I haven't quite figured out the proper way to do it yet.

Comment: FYI, I was able to accomplish what I wanted by adding an InverseProperty attribute to the Skills table referencing the SkillResponses. Only problem is I am fairly sure it's not filtering to only the current UserAssessment and I'm not sure how to accomplish that in my query... perhaps turning it into the sort of select projection you suggested would allow me to do this more easily. Guess I will find out soon.